# Create new column with elements of the first list if value is equal to the second list elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset df1 with two columns :

```
d1=[9,9,26,28,43,43,43,44,85]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
df1['sl']=""
```

And 2 lists with the same length (but not the same length than the df1) :

```
list1=[9,26,28,43,44,85]
list2=[2,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I would like to add in my column 'sl' (df1), the values of the list2 if the value of my column 1 (of df1) is equal to the elements of the list1.

I mean, expected output for df1:

```
0 sl
9 2
9 2
26 1
28 1
43 1
43 1
43 1
43 1
44 1
85 1
```

I have tried a lot of solution before posting but without success...

Thanks a lot,

AL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created by `zip` by both lists:

```
d1=[9,9,26,28,43,43,43,44,85]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)

list1=[9,26,28,43,44,85]
list2=[2,1,1,1,1,1]

df1['sl']= df1[0].map(dict(zip(list1, list2)))
print (df1)
    0  sl
0   9   2
1   9   2
2  26   1
3  28   1
4  43   1
5  43   1
6  43   1
7  44   1
8  85   1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and very efficient method !!!